# PHP regexp - remove all leading, trailing and standalone hyphens

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to remove all leading, trailing and standalone hyphens from string:

```
-on-line - auction- website
```

Desired result:

```
on-line auction website
```

**I came up with a working solution**:

```
^-|(?<=\s)-|-(?=\s)|-$
```

But it looks to me a little bit amateur (isn't it?). **So do you have a better solution**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
(?<!\S)-|-(?!\S)
```

example:

```
echo preg_replace('~(?<!\S)-|-(?!\S)~', '', '-on-line - auction- website');
```

Another possible pattern that uses a conditional statement: `-(?(?!\S)|(?<!\S.))`

This last one is interesting since it benefits of a single branch with a leading literal character. This way, the regex engine is able to quickly tests only positions in the string where the character appears (due to internal optimisations before the "normal" regex engine walk).

Note that the conditional statement isn't mandatory and can also be replaced with a non-capturing group adding a `:` (it doesn't change the result but it's longer):

```
-(?:(?!\S)|(?<!\S.))
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess it can be shortened to:

```
$repl = preg_replace('/(^|\s)-|-(\s|$)/', '$1$2', $str);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following:

```
-(?!\w)|(?<!\w)-
```

This either matches a dash which is followed by something that is not a word character, or a dash that is preceded by something that is not a word character.

Or if you want to put it otherwise, match all dashes which are not between two word characters.

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mA1yM7)

Answer (score 2):

**There's no reason you have to do everything in one regex.**  Split it into two or three.

```
s/^-\s*//;    # Strip leading hyphens and optional space
s/\s*-$//;    # Strip trailing hyphens and optional space
s/\s+-\s+/ /; # Change any space-hyphen-space sequences to a single space.
```

That's the sed/Perl syntax.  You'll adjust accordingly for the preg_replace syntax.

Comment: This will not remove the `-` in `auction- `

Comment: The OP needs to define exactly what "standalone hyphen" means, then.  The key point here is that it's not necessary, and is actually more confusing, to try to do everything to in a single regex.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can use `trim` and `rtrim` to remove any characters from the beginning and end of the string. After that you can use `str_replace` to remove the `-` from the middle.

```
$string = '-on-line - auction- website';
$string = trim($string, "-");
$string = rtrim($string,"-");
$string = str_replace("- ", " ", $string);
$string = str_replace("  ", " ", $string); //remove double spaces left by " - "
var_dump($string);
```

the result:

```
string(24) "on-line auction website"
```

You can stack that up into one line if you want:

```
$string = $string = str_replace("  ", " ", str_replace("- ", " ", rtrim(trim($string, "-"),"-")));
```